# Automate touching OK or Don't Allow on the UIAlertView iOS shows after -[CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation] in the simulator

Tags: ios, automated-tests

I'm writing user interaction tests with [Frank](http://www.testingwithfrank.com/) for my iOS application.  The tests stall when the `UIAlertView` iOS shows after I call `-[CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation]`

[image: UIAlertView iOS shows after I call -[CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation]]

Right now, I'm just automating it with the following applescript:

```
activate application "iPhone Simulator"

tell application "System Events"
    set _position to position of window of application process "iPhone Simulator"
    set _x to item 1 of item 1 of _position
    set _y to item 2 of item 1 of _position
    click process "iPhone Simulator" at {_x + 625, _y + 457}
end tell
```

Is there a better way?  I really just want to avoid the warning if possible.  If I can just write some files inside the `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` directory somewhere, that's fine too.  What I'm doing just feels like a supreme hack.